# Getting first image url using scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to get first url `"https://example.com/example.jpg"` using xpath `@src` but the results always `/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg`

```html
<img class="pimg" src="https://example.com/example.jpg" onerror="this.src = '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg'" title="test" alt="test" style="">
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: scrapy shell https://www.trendyol.com/versace?qt=versace
response.xpath('//a/div/div/img/@src').extract()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath was wrong, try this...

```
scrapy shell "https://www.trendyol.com/versace?qt=versace"
response.xpath('//img[@class="primg lazy"]/@data-original').extract()
```

Comment: It's being long time but could you explain your code block? How did you decide to use primg lazy as class name?